# windows 10 virtual machine with ubuntu, external server access

Tags: virtualbox, apache2, webserver

I have vitual box installed on my Windows 10 running Ubuntu.
I installed all packages to build a web server.
apache2, phpmyadmin, mysql...
through my internal network I can access my wordpress site running perfectly in the virtual machine through the ip 192.168.1.65.
but through the wan network I can not access.
I have already released the ports of my router in the port forwarding settings, in the dmz settings..
I have already freed all apache ports through sudo ufw apache command and still not resolved.
Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Just to confirm when you test access to 192.168.1.65 inside your network is that from a *different* machine than the host of the virtual box ubuntu?

Comment: possibly your ISP is blocking it; you would have to contact them if that's the issue.